# Get a document snapshot from the database and convert its ServerValue.TIMESTAMP value to a date

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When we read a `DocumentSnapshot` from the database, the value of all `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` fields is `{ '.sv': 'timestamp' }`. How can we read this value as a `Date` or an equivalent time-related value?

This is what we have tried:

```
// create a document reference
const documentReference = firestoreDb.collection('test').doc();

// write the document to the database
const writeResult = await documentReference.set({
  timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});

// read the document from the database
const documentSnapshot = await documentReference.get();

// the timestamp value is { '.sv': 'timestamp' }
console.log(documentSnapshot.data().timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a [Realtime Database server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#timestamp).  That's different than a [Firestore server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-servertimestamp).  Use this instead:

Node SDK

```
import { FieldValue } from '@google-cloud/firestore';

const timetamp = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

Web SDK

```
const timetamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

Comment: You should clarify in your question - are you writing code in a web client or on a server?

Comment: Yes, the node SDK is different than the web SDK.